# Getting the current git revision on openshift

Tags: git, openshift-online-2

I'm deploying to OpenShift with `git push` as specified.  Now I'm trying to set up deployment notifications with rollbar.com, but rollbar needs the git revision to log which commit is being deployed.  I'm using an openshift deploy hook, so I need to be able to know what the git revision is from the server, but git doesn't seem to be on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I was looking for the wrong revision when I was searching.  Turns out I can do:

```
cat ~/git/<app>.git/refs/heads/master
```